# Design tab is getting hanged in Visual Studio2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I am using VS2008 in Microsoft Windows XP OS with ServicePack-3, .NET framework 3.5

Design tab is getting hanged when i switch from Code behind(Code window) to designer in Visual studio2008.
Please Help in this situation.

Comment: please tell us your system's configuration....

Comment: in that case your system takes too much memory and your application is also so much heavy so it becomes into hang position while you switch over into design mode.

Comment: It is normal for the first time use in vs studio just wait and it will be ok after a few seconds...but if it hangs permanently on switching to design mode maybe you need to re istall your vs 2008.

Comment: @sukumar the visual studio is a basic tool for html design, and its heavy for design - I never use it. Ether see the results on web page back and fordware, or use ms expression for design.

Answer (score 0):

try installing sp1 for visual studio 2008
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10986

you can check fixed issues on sp1 from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950263